# this.state.text.split() is undefined error when using onSubmitEditing

Tags: facebook, react-native

According to Facebook's official documentation:

`onChangeText` takes a function to be called every time the text changes

**and**

`onSubmitEditing` takes a function to be called when the text is submitted

I'm following the official Facebook tutorial on [text input handling](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html#content), the code:

```
export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

takes a sentence and change all of its words into  emojis, but if I change `onChangeText` to `onSubmitEditing`, I get an error saying `this.state.text.split is not a function. (In 'this.state.text.split('')', 'this.state.text.split' is undefined)` when I submit my text.

Comment: is this a trivial question or is there some sort of implementation that you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there still something unclear since you haven't accepted the answer, OP?

Comment: There's ur internet points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct on this point, both `onChangeText` and `onSubmitEditing` take a callback function to be executed. The essential difference is the argument supplied to the callback function. `onChangeText` gives the new value as a string and `onSubmitEditing` executes the callback function with an object as first argument. You can view the result using

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({text}); console.warn('text', text);}}
  onSubmitEditing={(argument) => console.warn(Object.keys(argument))}
/>
```